# Apache POI reading cells with % sign

Tags: excel, apache-poi

Ho can I read cells with a % sign in it? If I have 105% in the Excel cell, POI tells me that this must be read as a number (which is fine). Doing so gives me 1.0d. I would expect to get 105 or 1.05d.

Comment: Sorry for the noise. My loop counter was wrong and I got the value of the same cell all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in Excel you have 1.05 formatted as a percentage which causes it to display as 105%. I would be really surprised if POI is not giving you 1.05... maybe you are displaying the number rounded to one decimal place?

Answer (score 2):

When Excel puts 105% in a cell, what it actually stores is the numeric (floating point) value 1.05, along with a formatting string

When you ask POI to give you the value of the cell, it'll supply the value that Excel wrote for you, in your case 1.05

POI also has classes that attempt to format cells based on the formatting strings applied to them, to return a string that's the value shown in Excel (or at least very close to that). The class to do that is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)

Code wise, you'd want something like this:

```
// Create a formatter, do this once
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);

.....

for(Cell cell : row) {
    CellReference ref = new CellReference(cell);
    // eg "The value of B12 is 12.4%"
    System.out.println("The value of " + ref.formatAsString() + " is " + formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
}
```

Which is cell A1 contained 105% in excel, stored as 1.05, would print "The value of A1 is 105%"